# How to exclude ip from dhcp scope

Tags: mikrotik-routeros

I have a mikrotik router that has dhcp enabled.
But i have some pc and printers on my network that i have assigned a static Ip address.
But sometimes when one of these pc is off , dhcp server assign his ip to dhcp clients.
So i want to know how can i exclude some ip addresses from dhcp so these ip will be never assigned to dhcp clients. ( i know how to do on windows server but i don't know on Mikrotik router )

Comment: Which Mikrotik router ?

Comment: You need to set up DHCP reservation

Comment: @harrymc Router OS 6.47.9

Comment: @John These static Ip addresses that i have on my network , are not configured on router. I just want that dhcp inside router should not assign these addresses to dhcp clients.

Comment: Set up DHCP scope on the router from .100 to .200 and then use .10 to .99 for static IP.  That will work very well.

Comment: @John , ok but i want to know if on mikrotik i can exclude an ip from assigning to clients , ( just the same way i can do in a Windows Server DHCP)

Comment: You can use the scope setup I described, and then IPs from .10 to .99 will not be assigned. Easy to do what you wish. Windows Server uses DHCP reservation to assign specific addresses.

Comment: @John And is possible to do dhcp reservation on mikrotik ?

Comment: You would need to look up the Microtik documentation. But please do clarify. Setting the Scope precludes assigning an IP outside the scope. DHCP Reservation assigns a specific IP (does not preclude an IP). You cannot exclude a specific IP within the DHCP Scope. You can exclude a machine (MAC Filtering) but not an IP within the Scope.  DHCP Reservation prevents the use of the reserved IP by any other machine.

Comment: @John On windows dhcp server i can  exclude a static IP address from the DHCP scope

Comment: I have posted an answer that I believe completely clarifies. Keep the DHCP Scope and the Static IP range very separate.

Answer (score 0):

The article
[Mikrotik - Change LAN Subnet](https://support.ringlogix.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/231/110/mikrotik---change-lan-subnet)
might pertain to your router and answer your question.

According to the article, two steps are required:

1. Add the New IP Range

> - Go to IP
> - Go to Pool
> - In the IP Pool window, click on the Blue Plus Sign to add
> - Enter in a Name (e.g.: cust-pool)
> - Enter in the address pool range (e.g.: 10.0.0.10-10.0.0.99)
> - Click OK
> - The new IP Pool now appears in the IP Pool list

2. Change the DHCP Pool

> - From the same DHCP Server, double click on "default" to change the Address Pool
> - Go to the Address Pool drop down menu and select the pool that was just created (e.g.: cust-pool)
> - Click OK
> - The new Address Pool is now selected for the DHCP server

For more details with screenshots, see the linked article.

Comment: i want to some ip addresses , that may be random , and that cannot be all inside a pool.

Comment: How do you want to exclude random addresses with a non-random rule?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a mikrotik router that has dhcp enabled.

Set up the router scope carefully - Say .100 to .200

> But i have some pc and printers on my network that i have assigned a
> static Ip address. But sometimes when one of these pc is off , dhcp
> server assign his ip to dhcp clients.

Set the Static IP for the desired PCs and Printers in the range .10 to .99 .  DCHP Scope will NOT assign addresses out of its scope of .100 to .200 .

> So i want to know how can i exclude some ip addresses from dhcp so
> these ip will be never assigned to dhcp clients.

As answered just above. Use IP addresses in the non DHCP zone and then the DHCP server will NOT assign such addresses.

DHCP Reservation is used for permit a PC set for DHCP to get the same IP address from Server or Router all the time. This is a very useful function but it is not the exclusionary function you want.

> (i know how to do on windows server but i don't know on Mikrotik
> router)

Fair but Microtik is NOT a Windows Server.